# Virtual Template Function Overload

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

```
template <class T, class U, class Child>
class Parent {
public:
  virtual T blah() {
     return gaga;
  }
protected:
  T gaga;
};

class Child : public Parent<double, double, Child> {
  virtual void blah(int overloaded) {
  }

  virtual void func() {
    blah();
  }
};

int main() {
  Child* p = new Child();
}
```

Why doesn't the code above compile? Why can't I overload my virtual function like that?

The errors I am getting:

```
prog.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void Child::func()’:
prog.cpp:16: error: no matching function for call to ‘Child::blah()’
prog.cpp:12: note: candidates are: virtual void Child::blah(int)
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:21: warning: unused variable ‘p’
```

Answer (score 4):

The method`void blah(int)` in `Child` hides the inherited `T blah()` in `Parent`. You can unhide it by adding the line

```
using Parent::blah;
```

to `Child`. If you want to be able to access `Parent::blah()` you have to make sure that the `using` statement is in public access section. So you would have to add

```
public:
  using Parent::blah;
private:
  ...
```

to the top of `Child` to make `Parent::blah()` visible to everything. You can also refer to the base class method explicitly with `Parent::blah()` instead of just `blah()`. More info is available [here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/strange-inheritance.html#faq-23.9).

Comment: Thanks. That fixed the problem and I can use it within the class... However, I can't use the Parent::blah() outside. For example: p->blah();

Comment: To do that you have to put the `using` statement in public scope. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score -1):

You just have different prototype for `blah` in child. For parent it is `T blah()` and for child it is `void blah(int)`, while it should be `double blah()` to produce correct overloading of virtual function.

Also, what do you have Child template argument in parent for?